# Generic class to handle two different HTTP response

Tags: c#, rest, generics

I am writing `REST api` calls to google classrooms. 
For example in the call - https://classroom.googleapis.com/v1/userProfiles/{`userId`}.
If the User has google classrooms enabled, I get a `json` of `UserProfile` type.

```
 {
     "id": "XXXXX",
     "name": {
        "givenName": "student1",
        "familyName": "User",
        "fullName": "student1 User"
       }
 }
```

Else, 
If the user does not have access, I get this.

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "@NotGoogleAppsUser The user is not a Google Apps user.",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
   }
}
```

The method to make `REST` calls is a `Generic` method which will be reused for all other calls returning many different types.

```
 public T SendRequest<T>(RequestWrapper wrapper)
    {


        RestSharp.Deserializers.JsonDeserializer deserial = new RestSharp.Deserializers.JsonDeserializer();
        var client = new RestClient(wrapper.Url);

        RestRequest request = CreateRequest(
            wrapper.Data,
            wrapper.Header,
             wrapper.Method);
        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);


        return deserial.Deserialize<T>(response);
    }
```

The problem is when I send `UserProfile` as the T type, I do not get the access code after the response being deserialized.

Is there any way I can redesign my classes so that I get all the `response` in a `T type`.

The initial idea was to create an error class and make `UserProfile` inherit it, 
which is not possible as `UserProfile` belongs to an `external DLL`.

Any other solutions to this ? 
TIA

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you check status code request before Deserialize? You can try same that:

```
RestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
HttpStatusCode statusCode = response.StatusCode;
int numericStatusCode = (int)statusCode;
if(numericStatusCode == 403) return null;
```

Comment: This is a case for forbidden, I have another case in which the Auth token has expired and need to regenerate it .